# How to select specific java plug-in to run applet

Tags: plugins, java, applet

I have installed jre 1.4.1 and jre 1.6.24 on my windows machine. I want test my applet on both the version. But after installing jre 1.6.24, I am not able to switch to 1.4.1.

The steps I am doing to change the jre version are as below,

1. **Deselected 1.6.24 from java control panel and selected 1.4.1.**
2. **unchecked "next generation plugin"
       from advanced tab of java control
       panel.**
3. **disable 1.6.24 plugins
       from "manage add-ons" of IE**

but still IE is using 1.6.24 to run the applet. Are there any more steps involved ?

Any help on this much appreciated !!!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You might try launching the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and specifying ..

```
<j2se version='1.4.1' />
```

..in the resources section.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I do not want to use jnlp.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing which I did to get it done, by removing the jre1.6.24 from the machine. Kindly let me know if you find better solution...